# Windows Batch File Ping an IP and display round trip time

Tags: batch-file, ping, latency

I wrote this out in C# but I need it written in a batch file. How can I ping an IP address and display (`echo`) the round trip time every 5 seconds in an infinite loop?

I know in C# there is

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

and with the use of a `continue` you can return back to the top of the loop but have no idea how to do that in a batch file.

Answer (score 1):

```
:start
sleep 5
rem Do something...
goto :start
```

Answer (score 1):

```
:LoopBack

FOR /F "delims=@" %%a IN ( 'ping 127.0.0.1' ) DO ( SET TRIP_TIME=%%a )
ECHO %TRIP_TIME%

REM Prompts you to enter a choice with a timeout of five seconds.
CHOICE /C YN /D N /N /T 5

call :LoopBack
```

Assuming that the last line of ping output is the round trip time you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
    for /L %%f in (1 0 2) do (
        ping 127.0.0.1 | call findstr "Average"
        if errorlevel 1 echo %date% %time% : Not Found
        choice /t 5 /c y /d y /n /m "" >nul
    )
```